# Ubuntu 14.04 "libopencv-dev" package don't have libraries and headers?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I install `libopencv-dev` package in Ubuntu 14.04,64bit.
After installation, I though the package should install the libraries and headers to `/usr`, but I can't find any libraries or headers.

Then I `dpkg -L libopencv-dev`, get those info:

```
igsrd@~>sudo dpkg -L libopencv-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-dev/copyright
/usr/share/OpenCV
/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake
/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules-release.cmake
/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_createsamples.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_haartraining.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_performance.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/opencv_traincascade.1.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/opencv_traincascade
/usr/bin/opencv_createsamples
/usr/bin/opencv_haartraining
/usr/bin/opencv_performance
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Is that mean the package doesn't have any libraries or headers?
It shouldn't be that situation, right?

Answer (score 0):

`libopencv-dev` is, as it's package description says, a meta package. It has dependencies to a number of packages that do contain the necessary libraries and header files, such as `libopencv-core-dev`, `libopencv-imgproc-dev` and so on.
Since dependencies are automatically installed, you indirectly have all you need. This is a standard pattern in packaging so you can either pick exactly the components you need or simply install the meta package.
If you are not sure, install `libopencv-dev`.

Comment: Well. If I wanna get opencv libraries and headers, what package should I install?

Comment: Sorry, I don't realize your comment. How can I "see" your edit? Where is the meta package?

Comment: Just install or reinstall `libopencv-dev`

Comment: No,no,no. I had installed `libopencv-dev` already and **it isn't what I want**. It's supposed that **contains the libraries and headers** like other `libxxx-dev` package is. That is why I confused with that package.